# Problems using Netbeans 8.0.1 and Tomcat 8.0.15

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

I'm trying to create a simple web project using Netbeans, but when I try to run or even debug the project, all the archives of the project get erased!
First I've thinked that it was something of the server, but I've created the same project without netbeans and it functions perfect, so I don't know why all the filles get erased, anyone knows how to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the scope of the question and the error you're chasing is very large which makes it difficult to find. You can try to narrow the scope by comparing your setup with one that is known to work.

I'd recommend creating a new Netbeans project following this [Quickstart](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html). Once you get the step-by-step example working, modify it little by little to mimic your original project. If you can reproduce your original error from within the new project, edit your question with more details.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial! But, still happening that Netbeans erase everything and then appears the message that it couldn't be able to found the project cause it doesn't exist! I don't know if its a problem of Tomcat or Netbeans... When I make a simple desktop application, Netbeans run it without any problems, and when I make simple .jsp pages and try it in my browser, the page function so I'm very confused